# Auto Get Data From API using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api

I would like to know if there's a way to create a program form node.js that will automatically get a new data on the API and save it from database?.

I already installed nodemon and try if its gonna work on my theory, but i failed.. hope you can help me.

by the way here's what i have so far:

```
    const request = require('request');

request('https://lc-txtconnect5.globe.com.ph/inbox?token=3a64892d865cd4e386b161767245fa0afc808c63957a7e495f65829a56b96b03&txtid=51talk', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  var messages = body.response.response;

  console.log(messages);

    messages.forEach(function(messages) {

        var tblmessage = messages.message;
        console.log(tblmessage);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so I understand your question right, you would like your program to get data from an API and save it to a datbase - and this should be done automatically.
One way of solving this is to write a cron-job which would run periodically .

Nodemon is NOT the solution here, Nodemon is to restart the program whenever a change was made to the node.js app.  This is used during development, when there are frequent changes and you don't want to manually restart your app for your changes to take effect.

Comment: cronjob will not refresh your code - cronjob is defined to run a command periodically, and in this case start your app.

Answer (score 1):

Get API wont hit till you trigger it by hitting it in browser or by cronjob . If you want to recieve data automatically from database if there is any changes or new data in database then use realtime api . For that you have to use websocket in nodejs.If this is what you want then i will give you more information about how to use websocket .

Comment: can you give me an info about website... right now i do have limited knowledge on nodejs.. because this my first time using it..

Comment: There is a framework called socket.io in nodejs . This framework helps you to create a bridge between  the client and server communication. It detects whenever there is any change in database and you can use your post api function inside your socket code so that whenever a new data is entered you can request the http api automatically. If you  think that what I said is useful to you then I will create a small code for you.so that you will get to know how exactly socket works

Comment: I saw also one of this on the other article... I think this might be useful on what I want to do...